# How to get a calendar link using Outlook REST API?

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi

I noticed that the Event object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#EventResource) contains a property called WebLink which you can use to open that event in the browser.

Is there any way to open a specific calendar in a browser ? Preferably passing also the current date and the view (day/week/month) ?

Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API doesn't provide a `WebLink` property for calendars. You can give feedback for this on http://officespdev.uservoice.com/.